# error when returning generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

The following code is a simple example of a program I am writing.

```
public class Y
{ }

public class X : Y
{ }

public class W : Y
{ }

public interface IAaa<T>
    where T : Y
{
    void Execute(T ppp);
}

public abstract class Aaa<T> : IAaa<T>
    where T : Y
{
    public abstract void Execute(T ppp);
}

public class Bbb : Aaa<X>
{
    public override void Execute(X ppp)
    { }
}

public class Ccc : Aaa<W>
{
    public override void Execute(W ppp)
    { }
}

public class Factory 
{
    public static IAaa<Y> Get(bool b)
    {
        if(b)
            return new Bbb();
        else
            return new Ccc();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAaa<Y> aa;
        aa = Factory.Get(true);
    }
}
```

when I compile it I get the following errors

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication3.Bbb'
>   to 'ConsoleApplication3.IAaa'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>
> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApplication3.Ccc'
>   to 'ConsoleApplication3.IAaa'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Rather than your problem, my suggestion is using better meaningful class names `;)`

Comment: You have missed something/oversimplified your example - the `Get` method will require a type parameter in both its definition and its call from `Main()`

Comment: I believe simply askig for a new Bbb or Ccc will not tell what is the type parameter in the base class Aaa<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the interface in the way you're trying to.  Lookup [covariance/contravariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx), you're trying to do the opposite of what's possible (you have in interface that could be `<in T>` but you're trying to use it like `<out T>`).

Take class `Bbb` for instance - it has an `Execute(X)` method.  What would happen if you tried to pass a `Y` (which may or may not be an `X`) to that?  The compiler doesn't allow it, because you never defined in the code what should happen in that case.

You can do what you want by creating and implementing another interface, `IAaa`.  E.g.

```
public interface IAaa
{
    void Execute(Y ppp);
}
```

Perhaps implemented like this, so that if you try to call it with an invalid type, a cast exception is thrown:

```
void Main()
{
        IAaa aa;
        aa = Factory.Get(true);
}

public class Y
{ }

public class X : Y
{ }

public class W : Y
{ }

public interface IAaa<T> : IAaa
    where T : Y
{
    void Execute(T ppp);
}

public interface IAaa
{
    void Execute(Y ppp);
}

public abstract class Aaa<T> : IAaa<T>
    where T : Y
{
    public abstract void Execute(T ppp);
    void IAaa.Execute(Y ppp)
    {
        this.Execute(ppp);
    }
    protected abstract void Execute(Y ppp);
}

public class Bbb : Aaa<X>
{
    public override void Execute(X ppp)
    { }
    protected override void Execute(Y ppp)
    {
        this.Execute((X)ppp);
    }
}

public class Ccc : Aaa<W>
{
    public override void Execute(W ppp)
    { }
    protected override void Execute(Y ppp)
    {
        this.Execute((W)ppp);
    }
}

public class Factory 
{
    public static IAaa Get(bool b)
    {
        if(b)
            return new Bbb();
        else
            return new Ccc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but I dont unerstand what you mean by "Take class Bbb for instance - it has an Execute(X) method. What would happen if you tried to pass a Y (which may or may not be an X) to that?". How can I pass Y to B.Execute if it can only take X

Comment: It works, but it seems a little bit confusing to me. If in your Main method you call Execute(new Y()) it fails because you are casting. If you call Execute(new X()) it works, but it actually goes through three methods to do what you want: Aaa class Iaa.Execute() and both Bbb class Execute(). If that is the kind of functionality you are looking for it may be fine for you. Otherwise you can try refactoring the classes and interfaces.

Comment: @amichaigerstl you are trying to use an instance of `Bbb` as an `IAaa<Y>`.  `IAaa<Y>` defines a method with signature `void Execute(Y)`.  Your `Bbb` class defines a method with signature `void Execute(X)`.  There is no way to change from `Y` to `X` without a possibility of failure.  You're right in saying that `Bbb.Execute` can only take `X`; you're trying to let it take `Y`, which is why it won't compile.

Comment: @AndreCruz totally agree...it's confusing, but it's a way to implement what the asker was trying to do: get an equivalent of `IAaa<Y>` that might be `Bbb` or `Ccc`.  On looking at this implementation, he may decide an alternative would be better after all.  As for why I included so many methods: it makes the public-facing methods of the classes type-safe, while still giving you the casting interfaces, much like `List<T>` and its `IList<T>` and `IList` interfaces: type-safe methods are public-facing, but interfaces exist for ones that take `object` and cast inside.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are missing a cast. I believe this is what you need:

```
public static IAaa<Y> Get(bool b)
{
    if(b)
        return (IAaa<Y>)(new Bbb());
    else
        return (IAaa<Y>)(new Ccc());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it compiles know but fails during runtime. there is an InvalidCasting exception

Comment: Your factory may need to be upstream of your template specialization to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You could cast to (`IAaa<Y>`) and your code would compile.
However it will not work and will fail at run-time.
Why?
Your classes `Bbb` and `Ccc` are specialized classes and the Execute method cannot process ALL types of `Aaa`. You have to tell C# / the compiler.

**UPDATE:**

By having a generic Factory you can get specialized instances of IAaa and your code should work.
In your `Program` you already know the type as you pass TRUE or FALSE to the Factory, so you need to explicitly tell C# the type of the Interface implementation you want to use.
(refactor the Factory class accordingly, I'm just sending what should compile)

```
public class Y
{ }

public class X : Y
{ }

public class W : Y
{ }

public interface IAaa<T>
    where T : Y
{
    void Execute(T ppp);
}

public abstract class Aaa<T> : IAaa<T>
    where T : Y
{
    public abstract void Execute(T ppp);
}

public class Bbb : Aaa<X>
{
    public override void Execute(X ppp)
    { }
}

public class Ccc : Aaa<W>
{
    public override void Execute(W ppp)
    { }
}

public class Factory<T> where T : Y
{
    public static IAaa<T> Get(bool b)
    {
        if(b)
            return (IAaa<T>)new Bbb();
        else
            return (IAaa<T>)new Ccc();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAaa<X> aa;
        aa = Factory<X>.Get(true);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just an example of how you could refactor the Factory class:

```
public class Factory<T, U>
    where T : Y
    where U : Aaa<T>, new()
{
    public static IAaa<T> Get()
    {
        return (IAaa<T>)new U();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IAaa<X> aa;
        aa = Factory<X, Bbb>.Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried casting but there is an InvalidCasting exception. so I even don't get to the Execute part.